# How to compare two comboboxes items if even atleast one match found count it c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to compare two comboboxes items if they have even single items match count that item and how to set condition for display message as match found?

combo10 already has IDs like

1001
1003
1004
1100

comboBox1 gets IDs when combo10 text get selected

My question is how to count repeated items(IDs) of combobox1 using c#(winforms)

Below is the code i have used in button event but it is not working

```
    var itms1 = combo10.Items;
    var itms2 = comboBox1.Items;

    foreach (var itm in itms2)
    {
        if (comboclass.Text == lblclasstext.Text)
        {
            if (itms1 == itm)
            {
                lbldone.Visible = true;
                lbltomark.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other alternative method is to double loop to compare list of each comboboxes

```
int repeatedItems = 0;
foreach (var cbItems1 in itms1)
{
    foreach (var cbItems2 in itms2)
     {
          if(cbItems1 == cbItems2){
              repeatedItems++;
         }  
     }
}
```

Comment: This one was not working i don't know why as it should be but changed it from  if(cbItems1 == cbItems2) to if(cbItems1.equals(cbItems2)) it is ok now tanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Adapt this to your code and you should get what you need.

```
        Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //add item if it does not exists
        if (!d.ContainsKey("1001"))
        {
            d.Add("1001", "XPTO");
        }
        //get the itens in dictionary
        var x = d.Count;
        if (x > 0)
        {
            //do stuff...
        }
```